# How is Round(11) equal to 3?

Tags: number-theory

I saw this on a Mathematical clock face. $1= \tan(45^{\circ})$, $2= \sqrt{4}$, 
$3=Round(11)$, and so on. 
How does $Round(11)$ equal $3$? I was told it has to do with unicode but I could not find it on the internet.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: One interpretation is that $11$ in base 2 is $11_2 = 1\cdot 2^1 + 1\cdot 2^0= 3$.  That doesn't explain why they would write it with Round($\bullet$) though.  The common interpretations of "Round" are to take to the nearest integer.  Are you sure it wasn't Round($\frac{11}{4}$)?  Or Round($\pi$)?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that 3base10 = 11base2 .  But that wouldn't require the Round function, so that's probably not it.

I looked up the values for the Unicode characters 1 and 3, and they're 31base16 and 33base16, respectively.  The characters corresponding to the values 11base10, 11base16, and 3 are all non-numerical things like "vertical tab"

Comment: @JMoravitz has gotta have it with Round(pi).

Comment: I hate these mathematical clocks.  They're so ridiculously unimaginative.

Comment: [Example watch face that uses $3=Round(11)$](https://faradayscienceshop.com/products/mathematicians-watch?t=fb) ([img permalink](http://imgur.com/a/UAFE6)). I think @ZevChonoles is correct, but it may not have been OP that made the mistake; the linked watch was probably copied from a clock like the one he posted below, but the copier didn't understand what they were looking at and copied $11$ instead of $\pi$.

Answer (score 13):

You read the clock wrong (though it's not really your fault).

[image]

What it says is 
$$\Large\operatorname{Round}(\pi)=3$$
where $\pi=3.14159\ldots$ is [this famous number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), but the clock (arguably incorrectly) uses the capital form of the Greek letter pi ($\Pi$), and the font chosen is very thin, so it does appear similar to 11.

Comment: To be fair, it looks more like a upper case pi, that is $\Pi$. Which is not really conventional.

Comment: Yeah but they use a $\Pi$ which is heinous.

Comment: Oh, I agree it's heinous, and the font they chose is particularly thin, so I agree it appears close to 11.

Comment: For your next magic trick, will you explain how $\operatorname{Log}(55) = 4$, and why $g = 10$ ? :)

Comment: Well g is again just rounding to 10m/s^2.

Comment: I think $g$ is the gravitational constant, so it should actually be $\text{round}(g)$ as well.

Comment: $\text{round} (\frac{g}{m\cdot s^{^-2}})$, I guess

Comment: @pjs36 ln(55) is $\textit{kind-of}$ close to 4, I suppose$\ldots$

Comment: Worse than the poor choice of pi character is [this watch](https://faradayscienceshop.com/products/mathematicians-watch?t=fb) ([img permalink](http://imgur.com/a/UAFE6)), which clearly copied a clock face like the one above but made the same mistake as OP and *actually used* $3=Round(11)$ instead of $3=Round(\pi)$; in fact, maybe OP was looking at this watch or a similar one and didn't even make the mistake personally, though clearly someone did.